# Flex 4: tabIndex is not working inside form

Tags: apache-flex

tabIndex is not working properly in the below flex code.

mx:AddChild tag is used to add Login.mxml in index.mxml as shown below:

index.mxml

```
<mx:Application
        xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
        xmlns:login="com.states.login.*"
        initialize="init()" 
        pageTitle="Demo" >

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public function init():void {
                Application.application.currentState = 'initState';
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:states>
        <mx:State name="initState">
            <mx:AddChild relativeTo="{MainCanvas}" position="lastChild">
                <login:Login id="Login"/>                   
            </mx:AddChild>
        </mx:State>
    </mx:states>

    <mx:VBox>
        <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" id="MainCanvas">
        </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Login.mxml

```
<mx:Application  
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" >

...

<mx:Form>
    <mx:FormItem label="Username:">
        <mx:TextInput id="username" tabEnabled="true" tabIndex="1"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="Password:">
        <mx:TextInput id="password" displayAsPassword="true" tabEnabled="true" tabIndex="2"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>

...
```

Tabbing is working when focus is outside the form in browser. But does not work when focus is inside the TextInput control.

The issue was resolved after doing below 2 changes:

1. Move the code in Login.mxml into index.mxml and removed AddChild method.
2. year is set to 2006 in xmlns:mx and xmlns:fx namespaces. (Not sure if this was the issue)

How to resolve the tabbing issue without removing AddChild method.

Comment: Could you be more precise:  How is it not working?  What is actually happening vs. what do you want to happen?

Comment: Tabbing is not working means on pressing tab button, cursor is not moved from one input control to another.

Comment: When I add your form to a empty project it works fine. So this tells me something else in your code is messing with it.

Strip down your code until it starts working and find your solution there to why it breaks your form.

Comment: Robin, after stripping down the code, I found AddChild is causing the issue. how to resolve it. I have updated the question.